# Ubuntu 13.04 with LinuxLive USB Creator and persistence forgets desktop background and keyboard layout

Tags: ubuntu, desktop-environment, live-usb, bugs

I'm using a live and persistent version of Ubuntu 13.04, created with LinuxLive USB Creator.

The persistence mostly works, including for documents and apps, however the desktop background image and keyboard layout settings have to be configured manually each boot; the system prompts to install to a hard drive as well.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at this post: [How do I set the default icon set and wallpaper for new users?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62927/how-do-i-set-the-default-icon-set-and-wallpaper-for-new-users)

#### Changing the wallpaper

Open a terminal and type `gconf-editor`. Now, navigate to `apps > gnome > background`. Edit the key `picture_filename` and type in the path of the desired wallpaper image. Try rebooting and check if it works. I have verified that this works with Ubuntu 10.04 in VirtualBox.

#### Keyboard layout

Well, every Linux distribution has the `/etc` directory I believe :)

Following is the content of `/etc/default/keyboard` in my machine. Try and/or adapt it:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

### Alternative approach

If the above method for setting the wallpaper didn't work out, you can try this alternative -- but not-so-straightforward -- method.

First, locate all the images in your system. Default wallpaper images could possibly in `/usr/share/backgrounds`. If you find it there, skip this step.

`find / -type f -name '*.png' -o -name '*.svg' -o -name '*.jpg' 2>/dev/null`

This would list a lot of images used by different applications. If you could manually screen them, then you should narrow down your choices.

Suppose, you determined that the image `desktop.png` is set as the wallpaper.

The next step would be to find all the file(s) that refer to the name of the image.

`find / -type f -exec grep 'desktop\.png' {} + 2>/dev/null`

If it shows a file, open that in some editor, replace the image location with the desire one, and reboot.

Comment: There is no 'apps > gnome > background' or similar, see here http://oi42.tinypic.com/25ar8rd.jpg Should I action the link at the top of your post first? If not then no need to tell me how, I'll just award you the rep and presume it works. I presume that couldn't possibly be right though, on top of literally everything else too, whats more important to Linux devs, getting some new users, or making everything perverse and obtuse?

Comment: Your comment is not clear to me -- what do you mean by "action the link?"

Comment: I was able to solve the question you have originally asked here with the solution previously presented. It seems it did not quite work out for you. Am updating the answer with an alternative, but involved approach, and would require some patience to try. And yes, configuring certain things may not be that easy in Linux, but that's a minority, and doesn't compare to the "enormous power" it provides otherwise. Good luck :)

Comment: I will presume that this works, also the first way presumably doesn't work for anyone else either, maybe it used to, I cannot see why it would be different only for me than anyone else. I cannot see the +50, presumably marking your question as correct has given you the rep.

Answer (score 0):

For your background, you can try to modify file in :

```
.gconf/desktop/gnome/background/%gconf.xml
```

And modify path of your file.

For the keyboard look at this file

```
/etc/default/keyboard
```

Comment: Browsing to .gconf takes me to /home/ubuntu/.gconf this has apps and desktop, they contain more directories each also with empty %gconf.xml files. I can find no 'background' directory. I haven't modified the OS beyond adding a few simple apps. What now?

Comment: For the keyboard I cannot find 'etc', however /home/ubuntu/.gconf/desktop/ibus seems promising, but still contains only directories and the empty %gconf.xml files.